# Why can't I send ether to my smart contract's address?

Tags: ethereum, solidity

```
contract_file = 'contract.sol'
contract_name = ':SimpleContract'

Solc = require('solc')
Web3 = require('web3')

web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
source_code = fs.readFileSync(contract_file).toString()

admin_account = web3.eth.accounts[0]

compiledContract = Solc.compile(source_code)
abi = compiledContract.contracts[contract_name].interface
bytecode = compiledContract.contracts[contract_name].bytecode;
ContractClass =  web3.eth.contract(JSON.parse(abi))

contract_init_data = {
    data: bytecode,
    from: admin_account,
    gas: 1000000,
}

deployed_contract = ContractClass.new(contract_init_data)
contract_instance = ContractClass.at(deployed_contract.address)
```

up until here, this works. However, one surprise was that the line
    msg.sender.transfer(amount);
in my contract wouldn't compile on web3, despite getting that line straight from the [common pattern section](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/common-patterns.html#withdrawal-from-contracts) of the solidity docs. Had to use Solc instead, because transfer() wasn't in 0.4.6...

Isn't transfer() a core part of ethereum? I would have expected that to exist in v 0.1

Anyway, I then try to add ether to the contract like this:

```
load_up = {
    from: admin_account, 
    to: deployed_contract.address, 
    value: web3.toWei(1, 'ether'),
}
web3.eth.sendTransaction(load_up)
```

and I get:

```
Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode
```

which doesn't give me much to work with. What am I doing wrong, and how do I debug issues like this in the future?

Comment: Can you post the code of your contract? Which version of solc are you using? And what kind of node do you use (main,test or local testrpc?)

Comment: check this https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3613/getting-invalid-opcode-error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out that I need to create a method on the contract with the `payable` keyword, for example:

`function AddEth () payable {}`

and then I can interact with my contract like this:

```
load_up = {
    from: admin_account, 
    to: deployed_contract.address, 
    value: web3.toWei(10, 'ether'),
}
deployed_contract.AddEth.sendTransaction(load_up)
```

Comment: how do i get transaction receipt from this function?